# RabbitMQ server won't start in CentOS 7

Tags: magento, rabbitmq

I installed Magento 2.3 which requires RabbitMQ. Using the instructions here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html I ran the following commands to install it:

```
wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.5.6/rabbitmq-server-3.5.6-1.noarch.rpm
rpm --import https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc
yum install rabbitmq-server-3.5.6-1.noarch.rpm
```

If I try one of the following commands:

```
rabbitmq-server
rabbitmqctl
```

I get this:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_misc,format,["rabbitmq-cli-~s",["9540"]],[]},{rabbit_cli,start_distribution,0,[]},{rabbit_cli,main,3,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
```

and if I run this command `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service -l`, I get this output:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-06-27 10:13:17 BST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8958 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 27 10:13:16 my.server.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker...
Jun 27 10:13:16 my.server.com su[8972]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
Jun 27 10:13:16 my.server.com su[9060]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
Jun 27 10:13:16 my.server.com su[9061]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
Jun 27 10:13:17 my.server.com rabbitmq-server[8958]: Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
Jun 27 10:13:17 my.server.com rabbitmq-server[8958]: rabbitmq-server.
Jun 27 10:13:17 my.server.com systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 27 10:13:17 my.server.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker.
Jun 27 10:13:17 my.server.com systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Jun 27 10:13:17 my.server.com systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
```

Please note, I have replaced my hostname with "my.server.com"

Also /var/log/rabbitmq/startup.log and startup.err both contain this:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_misc,quit,[0],[]},{rabbit_prelaunch,start,0,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
[FAILED]
```

and

```
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{rabbit_misc,quit,[0],[]},{rabbit_prelaunch,start,0,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix this by installing the latest rabbitmq-server with help from a script from https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/install

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
yum install rabbitmq-server
chkconfig rabbitmq-server on
```